# Normal Distribution Function

Tags: probability

[image]

I am new to Stochastic Calculus and this is only the 1st chapter, I have not taken a probability course except linear algebra and multivariable calculus, but I still want to learn despite it being hard. So, I was trying to answer the question where I had to show that if X is a normal distribution with the given mean and variance, then Y = alpha*X + Beta, with Y ~ N(alpha*mu + Beta, alpha^2 * sigma^2) is also a normal distribution. I wrote a proof saying that Y is a normal distribution since its value is just a coefficient applied to X ~ N(mu, sigma^2) but it was not enough as the picture shows. I do not understand this solution. For example: Why is that after integrating the Exp, we get an alpha out in constant outside, the exponent of Exp becomes expanded (How is it expanded?) and how do we get a primes in the third line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example: Why is that after integrating the Exp, we get an alpha out in constant outside,

he did the following variable change:

$$z=\alpha x+\beta$$

thus

$$dz=\alpha dx$$

$$dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}dz$$

> Why is that after integrating the Exp,  the exponent of Exp becomes expanded

for the same reason, being

$$x=\frac{z-\beta}{\alpha}$$

and substituting you get that exponent.

Now  you integrand is still a Gaussian with a new mean

$$\mu'=\alpha \mu+ \beta$$

and a new variance

$$(\sigma')^2=\alpha^2\sigma^2$$

Comment: So for that same line, last integrand's exponent, I will have to just substitute the values of N for Y distribution for mean and variance values, and subtitute x = (zeta - Beta)/ alpha to get that exponent, correct? and now I understand the whole picture.

Comment: Also, as it says in the solution in the first line, why is Y less than y in P(Y<y) and then why does (y-beta)/alpha becomes the upper bound in the integrand? One last question, where does variable z come from? Is it just a variable selected to perform variable change? Thank you.